# How to understand root cause of System.IO.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, dll, telerik, filenotfoundexception

I'm working with quite a complicated environment:

There are two main executables: `<Application_Server>.exe` and `<Application>.Desktop.exe`, a server application and a client application. Both applications are not to be modified.

In order to add functionality, `DLL` files can be added in the `Modules` subdirectory of both server and client runtime directories.

Last week, I had started up a client application, and now this seems not to work anymore. This would be due to the lack of the `Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.dll`, but this makes not sense: last week I also did not have that file in my runtime directory and still everything was working fine.

Can you find out where I should look in order to understand why my application now is asking to that `Telerik` related file?

This is my `NLog`-based output file:

```
2022-06-13 09:13:22.0707 | Application_Client.Desktop.App | Uncaught exception in MainWindow. --- System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions, Version=2016.2.822.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions, Version=2016.2.822.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions, Version=2016.2.822.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions, Version=2016.2.822.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(String assemblyString)
   at Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.OnReflectionOnlyResolve(ResolveEventArgs args, DirectoryInfo directory)
   at System.AppDomain.OnReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\<Runtime_Directory>\Application_Desktop.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions, Version=2016.2.822.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ce17eeaf1d59342
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This is an inspection only bind.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\<Runtime_Directory>\Application_Desktop.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/Modules/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/Modules/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/Modules/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/<Runtime_Directory>/Modules/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions/Telerik.OpenAccess.35.Extensions.EXE.

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<GetNotAllreadyLoadedModuleInfos>b__2(FileInfo file)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.GetModuleInfos(String path)
   at Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.GetModuleInfos(String path)
   at Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerLoad()
   at Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.Initialize()
   at Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.Run()
   at Application_Client.Desktop.Bootstrapper.InitializeModules() in D:\a\1\s\Application_Client.Desktop\Bootstrapper.cs:line 73
   at Prism.Unity.UnityBootstrapper.Run(Boolean runWithDefaultConfiguration)
   at Application_Client.Desktop.App.StartUp(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in D:\a\1\s\Application_Client.Desktop\App.xaml.cs:line 46
   at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at Application_Client.Desktop.App.Main()
```

**Edit: callstack**
Hereby the callstack of my problem:

```
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks) Line 1859  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(string assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool forIntrospection) Line 1743 C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(string assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, bool forIntrospection) Line 1722    C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(string assemblyString) Line 328  C#
    Prism.Wpf.dll!Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.OnReflectionOnlyResolve(System.ResolveEventArgs args, System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.OnReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolveEvent(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly assembly, string assemblyFullName) Line 3191   C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() Line 1517 C#
    Prism.Wpf.dll!Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.GetNotAllreadyLoadedModuleInfos.AnonymousMethod__2(System.IO.FileInfo file) Unknown
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManyIterator<System.IO.FileInfo, Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> source, System.Func<System.IO.FileInfo, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo>> selector)    Unknown
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Buffer<Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo>.Buffer(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo> source)  Unknown
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo> source) Unknown
    Prism.Wpf.dll!Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerModuleInfoLoader.GetModuleInfos(string path) Unknown
    [AppDomain (Application.Desktop.exe, #1) -> AppDomain (DiscoveryRegion, #2)]    
    Prism.Wpf.dll!Prism.Modularity.DirectoryModuleCatalog.InnerLoad()   Unknown
    Prism.Wpf.dll!Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.Initialize()   Unknown
    Prism.Wpf.dll!Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.Run()  Unknown
    Application.Desktop.exe!Application.Client.Desktop.Bootstrapper.InitializeModules() Line 73 C#
    Prism.Unity.Wpf.dll!Prism.Unity.UnityBootstrapper.Run(bool runWithDefaultConfiguration) Unknown
    Application.Desktop.exe!Application.Client.Desktop.App.StartUp(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e) Line 46    C#
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application..ctor.AnonymousMethod__1_0(object unused)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(object obj)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 980  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 928  C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Line 917    C#
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
    Application.Desktop.exe!Application.Client.Desktop.App.Main()   Unknown
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are working with [plugin architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support) and are experiencing a bit of dll hell.

Without knowing the depths of the app or what runtime you're working (I assume it's .NET Framework), it's difficult to say exactly where the problem is but the crux of it is this: The runtime is looking for a dependency and it's not finding it.

Take a look at the [AssemblyResolve event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=net-6.0). Essentially, when the framework is asking for a dependency, this handler fires. Returning `null` is a "not found" and then the framework will look for the dependency in the "usual places".  Places like

- the same directory as executing assembly
- the plugins folder
- the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)

The main challenge with plugins (in my experience) is including dependencies and getting those dependencies loaded by the host. Take a look at how the locations of these modules of yours are identified and how/whether dependencies are included.

Changes to your filesystem or environment can produce these kinds of problems. Maybe your app was working and a Git Clean took out the DLL in the program directory. Maybe the dll is loaded into the GAC but the app is now expecting a different version.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    }

    private Assembly? CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object? sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var filePath = GetPathFromName(args.Name);
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            return Assembly.Load(filePath);
        else
            return null;
    }

    private string GetPathFromName(string name) => "my logic here";


}
```